# How do you turn off a redstone torch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

As seen in many videos, the redstone torch can be switched on:

[image: on redstone torch]

and off:

[image: off redstone torch]

(pic found in web)

How do I achieve the second one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Power the block which the torch is attached to. It must be an opaque, solid, full block (so not glass, side of stairs etc; in particular glowstone and sea lanterns also count as transparent). You can power the block by running redstone signal into it (through powered redstone dust or repeater/comparator pointed into it) or by powering the block directly with a lever or a button. Similarly, attaching the torch to a redstone block will extinguish it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Power it with Redstone. You can do this with a lever, or a line of dust running into it (as seen in the second picture)

Answer (score 0):

So under that block place two blocks. Delete the middle block, then place a Redstone torch in the middle block. That's how Redstone torches work.